# Minimizing the NLL of a t-distribution derived from a NIG prior

Tags: likelihood, t-distribution, marginal-distribution

My question concerns [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.10060) which is a little too succinct for me to understand. The context is the following. Suppose $y$ is Normal distributed, with a Normal-Inverse-Gamma prior,

$$
y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) \\
\mu \sim N(\gamma, \sigma^2\nu^{-1}), \quad
    \sigma^2 \sim \Gamma^{-1}(\alpha, \beta).
$$

The marginal distribution of $y$ after integrating out $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ is,

$$
L^{NIG} = t\left(y | \gamma, \frac{\beta(1 + \nu)}{\nu\alpha}\right).
$$

The paper then says the following (page 2, first column, near the bottom): "... and can also be shown with some mathematical rigor by finding,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu}\log{L^{NIG}} = 0 \quad if \beta(\nu) \propto \frac{1}{1 + \nu^{-1}},
$$

to reveal that $\log{L^{NIG}}$ does not depend on $\nu$ and thus $L(\omega)$ is minimized, independent of the data, by sending $\nu \to 0$ and, for instance, following a path along $\beta(\nu) = \tfrac{1}{1 + \nu^{-1}}$."

What does this actually mean?